# Do Resource Extraction Sites affect anything other than ship spawn rates?

Tags: elite-dangerous

The wikia entry for [Resource Extraction Sites](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Resource_Extraction_Site) focuses mainly on ship spawn rates across sites of different intensity levels.

Do RES's affect anything other than ship spawn rates?

If I'm not concerned with bounties, can I land anywhere in the rings and still be just as successful at mining? Or does proximity to an RES affect things like asteroid composition (or the chances of finding certain metals/minerals)?

If proximity does have an effect, what are the distances involved?

Comment: I've since discovered that the intensity level of the RES directly affects the ship type and combat rank of AI spawns

Answer (score 1):

There is a mining yield bonus of 100% (double yields) when you are within 20km of a RES site.  So if you are well-armed, it might be worthwhile to endure the constant stream of scans and attacks that you'll get.